# How to add an event handler only fire once after transaction committed in sqlalchemy

Tags: events, transactions, sqlalchemy

I'm writing some functions using sqlalchemy. These functions are called inside transaction, like:

```
def create_order(session, *arg, **kw):
    # create order object
    order = Order(xxxx=xxx)
    session.add(order)

    # order extra operations
    order_extra_data = OrderExtraData(yyyy=yyyy)
    session.add(order_extra_data)

    # more operations
    ....

    # email should be sent to the order's owner
```

After order has been successful created, email should be sent to the user. But at the end of create_order, the transaction has not yet committed, and maybe abort by later code. So this function should not send mail directly. Instead it should register a one-time event handler that be triggered only after the session has been committed (And not fire and clear if the transaction is rollback or close). How can i implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can listen for the session [`after_commit`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.SessionEvents.after_commit) event with `once=True`:

```
def create_order(session, ...):
    ...
    @event.listens_for(session, "after_commit", once=True)
    def _send_email_after_commit(session):
        send_email()
```

If you anticipate rolling back and reusing the session down the road (and don't the listener to fire after the rollback), you'll also need to remove the event in the event of a rollback:

```
def create_order(session, ...):
    ...
    @event.listens_for(session, "after_commit", once=True)
    def _send_email_after_commit(session):
        send_email()

    @event.listens_for(session, "after_soft_rollback", once=True)
    def _remove_event_listener_on_rollback(session, prev_transaction):
        event.remove(session, "after_commit", _send_email_after_commit)
```

Comment: Great thx, I'm also reading the document on events. Is it guarantees that either after_commit and after_soft_rollback be called (if calling session.close() directly, will after_soft_rollback triggered?).  And why using after_soft_rollback instead of after_rollback?

Comment: @jayven I'm fairly certain that a transaction is guaranteed to either be committed (`after_commit`) or rolled back (`after_soft_rollback`). The only case where I'm not sure is if a transaction hasn't been started yet, but that almost never happens. `Session.close` also doesn't matter because you won't be able to reuse the session after it's closed (and any new sessions you create won't have the listeners you attached to other sessions in the past). Use `after_soft_rollback` because it's the event that corresponds to `session.rollback()`; `after_rollback` corresponds to a SQL `ROLLBACK`.

Comment: Thx for your explanation, this helps me a a lot .

Comment: Thanks. I used this to launch a task on instance insert. To protect against rollback or delete, I added a test in the after_commit event to check the inserted instance is still persistent. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75032864/4653485.